# 32bitSafePerl: Command not found

Tags: macos, bash, perl, terminal

When I the `with` command from this [repository](https://github.com/morgant/tools-osx), it should return help as it says in the script; `if(!$ARGV[0]) {$help = 1;}`. However, terminal returns an error `/usr/local/bin/32bitSafePerl: line 69: : command not found`. I checked that 32bitSafePerl exists at that location. I didn’t change anything in the script, so why is this error caused?

The line 69 of 32bitSafePerl is `"$interpreter" "/tmp/32bitSafePerl/${command}" "$@"`. You can find the whole script [here](https://github.com/morgant/tools-osx/blob/master/src/32bitSafePerl)

Comment: That error isn't complaining about `32bitSafePerl` it is complaining about the value of `$interpreter` not existing when `32bitSafePerl` tries to run it. Run `/bin/bash -x /usr/local/bin/32bitSafePerl` and see what binary it is trying to run when it fails.

Comment: What does `$interpreter` contain? From the two colons in the error message, something is blank that shouldn't be

Comment: Check the value of `$interpreter` and `$command`.  There is an `if` with a bunch of `elif`'s, but no `else` - that is asking for trouble.  For example, what happens if `version_major` was 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message indicates that `32bitSafePerl` cannot execute the program indicated by `$interpreter` because `$interpreter` is empty.

---

The value `$interpreter` is dependent of the value returned by

```
sw_vers -productVersion | cut -d . -f 2
```

The script only works if the above returns `5`, `6`, `7` or a value less than-than-or-equal to `4`.

In your case, it returns `10`, so `$interpreter` is left empty. You will need to extend the `if` that starts at line 24 of `32bitSafePerl`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the first condition to `[ ($version_major -eq 7) || ($version_major -gt 7) ]`. It seems to work. Do you know that if I should run it in 32bit mode or not?